HTMX Javascript API is missing OOB swap?
Im using JS API of the HTMX library to add contents. for example:
htmx.ajax('GET', url, {
    target: '#js-product-list',
    swap: 'beforeend', // Adding new stuff to already existing content
})
.then(() => {
...

Now lets say I would like to also update filter component on the page. Is it possible using JS API (without hx-* attributes)?
I tried
htmx.ajax('GET', url, {
    target: '#js-product-list',
    swap: 'beforeend',
    swapOptions: {
        swapOOB: '#js-filter-wrapper'
    }
})
.then(() => {
...

Markup details:


htmx.ajax('GET', url, {
        target: '#js-product-list',
        swap: 'beforeend',
        swapOptions: {
            swapOOB: '#js-filter-wrapper'
        }
    })
<div class="container position-relative" id="js-main-content">
    <header>
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between mx-1 my-3" id="js-filter-wrapper">
            Filter content
        </div>
        <div class="mt-3 ms-1" id="js-main-title-wrapper">
            <h1>Heading</h1>
        </div>
    </header>
    <main class="row" id="js-product-list">
        Product list content
    </main>
</div>



This is what will be returned in response:


<div id="js-filter-wrapper" hx-swap-oob="#js-filter-wrapper">
    Updated filter that will replace current filter
</div>

<div>
   New products that will be appended to current ones using beforeend selector
</div>




why don't you want to use (without hx-* attributes)?

I heard it's bad for SEO because of unknown attributes. Also I usually need to run animations using https://gsap.com/ library after ajax request which would probably work using htmx events but I find it cleaner to use the JS API.

you can use the htmx.on function to listen for the htmx:afterSwap event, htmx.ajax call updates the #js-product-list component, and once the update is complete, the htmx:afterSwap event is triggered. or use out-of-band (OOB) swaps, which works out of the box with multiple updates in a single request. then use the function you have

In your html you can add this code snippet : 





So you suggest using attributes? I'm afraid it would not be good for SEO

have you tried using js to make ajax request then update both parts of page using query-selectors

Could you please provide example? AFAIK swap can not have more than one target.

I found out it is possible to use selectOOB using the JS API https://htmx.org/api/


swapOptions - additional optional parameters for swapping
selectOOB - selector for the content to be swapped out-of-band (equivalent of hx-select-oob)


Do you know how and if it is possible to use it to swap the filter OOB way?

probably but you didn't provide more info about your html format, it makes it difficult. but I will provide an example for you.

I have provide you the updated function based on your html. check if that helps

To swap the filter OOB way, You will need to update the components, you desire . I have provided an example.
<div id="js-product-list">
    <!-- Product list content here -->
</div>
<div id="js-filter-wrapper" hx-swap-oob="true">
    <!-- Filter component content here -->
</div>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>HTMX Example</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/htmx.org@1.6.1"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container position-relative" id="js-main-content">
    <header>
        <div id="js-filter-wrapper">
            <!-- Initial filter component content -->
        </div>
        <div class="mt-3 ms-1" id="js-main-title-wrapper">
            <h1>Heading</h1>
        </div>
    </header>
    <main class="row" id="js-product-list">
        <!-- Initial product list content -->
    </main>
</div>

<script>
function updateComponents(url) {
    htmx.ajax('GET', url, {target: '#js-product-list', swap: 'beforeend'})
        .then((response) => {
            const parser = new DOMParser();
            const doc = parser.parseFromString(response, 'text/html');

            // Extract and update the filter component
            const newFilter = doc.querySelector('#js-filter-wrapper');
            if (newFilter) {
                document.querySelector('#js-filter-wrapper').innerHTML = newFilter.innerHTML;
            }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error('Error updating components:', error);
        });
}

// Example usage
updateComponents('/your-endpoint');
</script>

</body>
</html>




Unfortunately that did not help. The filter content gets appended to the existing (under the filter instead of replacing it), only the new product list content should be appended. I've updated the question with markup details and some more explenations.

hx-swap-oob works but it would be ideal to not use the hx tags because of the SEO

I just realized I can add the hx-swap-oob attribute on backend only in case it is AJAX request and so it will not be visible for robots. This solves my concerns about SEO. Thank you for your efforts.

@Askalot yeah you welcome. always happy to help.

You can issue separate HTMX requests to update different components. This is often the simplest approach if the components you want to update are distinct and their updates do not depend on each other.
htmx.ajax('GET', productUrl, {
    target: '#js-product-list',
    swap: 'beforeend'
})
.then(() => {

});

htmx.ajax('GET', filterUrl, {
    target: '#js-filter-wrapper',
    swap: 'innerHTML' 
})
.then(() => {

});


In my case it does not make sense to update one without updating the other. Also I want the same endpoint on the server for both ajax and full-page request for SEO purposes and this would require unnecessary endpoint that would not work for full-page requests.
